# ScrollBar gets stuck when defining Max and Min

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-plugin, scrollbar

I am trying to implement a `ScrollBar` to my Eclipse View and have this method to setup its behavior. When I run the program, no matter how long the `List<Number> data` is, the thumb will be as big as the `ScrollBar` and not able to move. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I already debugged the program and as soon as `ScrollBar` maximum is set, the thumb fills the bar.

```
private void setupScrollBar(ScrollBar scrollBar, List<Number> data) {
    // Set max/minimum
    if (data.size() > 0) {
        Comparator<Number> comparator = new Comparator<Number>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Number o1, Number o2) {
                return (int) (o2.doubleValue() - o1.doubleValue());
            }
        };

        double max, min;
        data.sort(comparator);
        max = data.get(data.size() - 1).doubleValue();
        min = data.get(0).doubleValue();

        scrollBar.setMax(max);
        scrollBar.setMin(min);
        scrollBar.setVisibleAmount(100 * (max-min));
    } else {
        scrollBar.setMax(0);
        scrollBar.setMin(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Eclipse normally uses SWT how are you integrating JavaFX with Eclipse?

Comment: @greg-449 I use FXCanvas and set a Scene to it
`public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    canvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NO);
    SplitPane mainSplit = new SplitPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainSplit);
    canvas.setScene(canvas);
}`

Comment: @greg-449 I used e(fx)clipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) produces a reverse ordered `List` and as it was pointed out by [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian), because of the `int` casting you will get `1 == 1.9` and `1.9 == 2.8` but `1 != 2.8`.

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

To fix this:

- You can use double comparison like `data.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Number::doubleValue));`.
- or could modify the `compare` method of your `Comparator` instance to `return (int) Math.signum(o1.doubleValue() - o2.doubleValue());`

The other problem is how you set the [visibleAmountProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#visibleAmountProperty) of the `ScrollBar`: `(max-min)` returns the **full range** of the `ScrollBar`, so setting this property to this value already produces the thumb to fill the 100% available space.

You can fix this, if e.g. you would like to set the thumb for a percentage:

```
final double PERCENTAGE = 30.0;
scrollBar.setVisibleAmount((max-min) / 100.0*PERCENTAGE);
```

This snippet will result in having the thumb to fill 30% of available space.

Comment: It's not a good `Comparator` at all, since it doesn't satisfy the condition that equality is transitive. E.g. using that comparator you'd get `1 == 1.9` and `1.9 == 2.8` but `1 != 2.8`, so this doesn't satisfy the contract of `Comparator`. Either `Math.signum` should be applied before casting to `int` or simply `Comparator.comparingDouble(Number::doubleValue)` should be used...

Comment: Thanks @fabian for the correction. I just noticed that the order will be reversed, so I totally overlooked the problem with the int casting.